# Detect Ctrl + Left Click in Windows

Tags: c#, global-hotkey

I want my program to pop up when I hit the control key + left click (like babylon does).
I know how to register global hotkeys, but I dont klnow how to combine a mouse click.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay for a personal project but you can't do this on your user's machine.  It breaks lots of programs, including Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great article on global keyhooks *and* global mouse hooks on CodeProject

> This class allows you to tap keyboard and mouse and/or to detect their activity even when an application runs in the background or does not have any user interface at all. This class raises common .NET events with KeyEventArgs and MouseEventArgs, so you can easily retrieve any information you need.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

Using that implementation, or the ideas in it, your program can know when a left click happens in any application, and what the state of the Control key is at the time.

Keep in mind that some other apps define behavior for Ctrl-Left-Click.  Overriding that behavior could create a confusing experience for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows hooks which can be used to hook to the keyboard and mouse events outside your form. This website explains how you can set a windows hook:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804